# How do I search in lists with irssi?

Tags: irc, irssi

I would like to be able to search like this:

```
/window list | grep ruby
```

I have installed grep.pl to do so, but it still fails.
The syntax says to do

```
/GREP [-i] [-w] [-v] [-F] <perl-regexp> <command to run>
```

But even typing /grep gives "Unknown command" in irssi.

What is a good way to find the number for specific channels? I keep on losing track of their numbers and typing /join #fullchannel name is often long and I often forget if the channel uses 1 or 2 #-symbols.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, make sure the script is loaded correctly by doing:

```
/script load grep
```

or

```
/script load autorun/grep
```

(if the grep.pl file is in your autorun directory)

Then, here is the proper command:

```
/grep ruby /window list
```

Comment: I blush! I ran /script load grep.pl, instead of /script load autorun/grep.pl! Thanks :)

Comment: Does not work for me when trying to search for a channel: "/GREP foo /list"

Comment: I really wish we could figure out why this doesn't work with `/list`.

Comment: @BrunoBronosky  [`/betterlist.pl`](https://github.com/irssi/scripts.irssi.org/blob/master/scripts/betterlist.pl) can search for channels using regex.