# irssi irc /list command

Tags: irc, irssi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I search in lists with irssi?](https://superuser.com/questions/296125/how-do-i-search-in-lists-with-irssi)

Folks,
  The irssi irc client operates in a condensed window, without the option of scrolling up and down through output.  So when i run the /list command on a busy irc network, is there any way to pipe that output to a file?
  Any way to do :

```
/list | grep -i blah
```

Is there a shortcut to scroll irssi window?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can scroll. Have you tried page up/down?

Comment: updown on mbp?  dont know what that is :)

Comment: @Phoshi: Have fun searching in 13,000 channels on FreeNode! :P

Comment: @Clustermagnet: Some networks don't want you to do this because of the amount of traffic it takes, and some even automatically disconnect you for flooding. You might want to try a website instead which makes it handy to search for channels [on](http://irc.netsplit.de/channels/?net=freenode) and [across](http://irc.netsplit.de/channels/) networks.

Comment: guys, solved!  on mbp you can use /elist -min 100, then hit fn+arrow up :)

Answer (score 0):

Another interesting way of listing interesting channels:

- Install elist addon for irssi http://scripts.irssi.org/
- /elist -min 100

  on macbook pro, using iterm, hit FN+arrow keys for page up/dn in irssi :)